# Fastest way to retrieve meta information from ios Media Library?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to retrieve meta information from the ios media library and then send it to the server in json.

However, I found that looping through the MPMediaQuery result and pulling the meta information to be very slow.

```
MPMediaQuery *query = [[MPMediaQuery alloc]init];
MPMediaPropertyPredicate *predicate = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:MPMediaTypeMusic] forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyMediaType];
[query addFilterPredicate:predicate];

NSMutableArray *songs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
songs = [query items];

[songs enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    [obj valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
    [obj valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration];
    [obj valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];
    [obj valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle];
    [obj valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyGenre];
    [obj valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTrackNumber];
}];
```

For a library of 9000 songs, it can take upwards of 25 seconds to finish the enumeration loop.

Is there a faster way to retrieve the meta information in bulk? ValueForProperty seem very inefficient in this case (each call in the loop adds about 5 seconds).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs for `MPMediaItem` state that using `enumerateValuesForProperties:usingBlock:` is usually faster than making individual calls to `valueForProperty:`. Try this:

```
NSSet *properties = [NSSet setWithArray:@[ MPMediaItemPropertyTitle, MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration, MPMediaItemPropertyArtist,  MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle, MPMediaItemPropertyGenre, MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTrackNumber ]];

[songs enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    MPMediaItem *item = (MPMediaItem *)obj;
    [item enumerateValuesForProperties:properties usingBlock:^(NSString *property, id value, BOOL *stop) {
        // do something with this property / value pair
    }];
}];
```

Comment: I have managed to cut down my time by half using your suggestion. Thanks! Is there any other optimization I can do?

Comment: That's all I know. Perhaps you could cache results and only get the attributes of items as you need them.